# How to set default text at UITextField in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextfield

Following is my code:

```
- (void)getAge:(NSString *)age getGender:(NSString *)gender  getLocation:(NSString *)location getPrefAge1:(NSString *)age1 getPrefAge2:(NSString *)age2 getPrefGender:(NSString *)prefGender getPrefLocation:(NSString *)prefLocation getImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    self.textFieldAge.text=age;
    self.textFieldGender.text=gender;
    self.textFieldLocation.text=location;
    self.textFieldPrefGender.text=prefGender;
    self.textFieldPrefAge1.text=age1;
    self.textFieldPrefAge2.text=age2;
    self.textFieldPrefLocation.text=prefLocation;

    self.imageProfilePic.image=image;
}
```

I get these value from another viewController I want to set these textFields with the above values. Can anyone help?
I am new to iOS.

This the method where I am calling the above method :

```
-(IBAction)editpro:(id)sender
{
    ProfileEditViewController *profileEdit= [[ProfileEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileEditViewController" bundle:nil];

    [profileEdit getAge:_labelAge.text getGender:_labelGender.text  getLocation:_labelLocation.text getPrefAge1:_labelPrefAge1.text getPrefAge2:_labelPrefAge2.text getPrefGender:_labelPrefGender.text getPrefLocation:_labelPrefLocation.text getImage:self.profilepic.image ];
    NSLog(@"Gender :%@",_labelGender.text);

    [profileEdit.saveProfile setHidden:YES];
    [self presentViewController:profileEdit animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: This part looks ok. How (or more importantly : when) are you calling this method? Are this textfields `IBOutlets` from storyboards? If so, calling this method before `- (void) viewDidLoad` will not work, ass textfields will still be `nil`

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? We need to know the problem to propose a solution

Comment: @sasquaztch  Actually the problem is that after the method execution it's  not placing the values at the text fields

Comment: @Lousiowayt yeah I think this is the problem where the method is called before  - (void) viewDidLoad . So can you suggest me what to do for placing the strings at the textFields?

Comment: @Lousiowayt  thank you for your suggestion I am able to solve the problem        . I just added another method to call after viewDidLoad is called .

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if:

- Text fields are hooked up in Interface Builder or correctly initialized programmatically.
- You set those properties in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the following things, your code will not work if one of these is the case or can be all too :

- Text fields should be linked to their `IBoutlets`, that is self.textFieldAge should not be `nil`.
- Also, the object or view controller you are calling this function of `getAge`, check if that object is not `nil`.

Comment: I have checked that the textfields are connected to the 'IBoutlets' and they are not nil and the objects are also not nil.I think the problem is that the method is calling before - (void) viewDidLoad method. so can you please suggest any solution?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but solution to that is quiet simple. You can store that data in a separate custom class object or a dictionary (I would recommend the class, because it is more neat) which you can create declare and initialize in this method. And later on in the view did load, you can use that object. Tell me if that is understandable, if not I will try to elaborate more or provide the code for it.